# SAP B1 DI-API replaces character on save

Tags: sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I wrote a small c# service importing tracking numbers to a single UDF separated by a `,` character (comma). The problem is that **occasionally (maybe every 200th document) a comma is saved as a semi-colon**.

A kind of similar issue I have is with the Amazon importer where I add a comment. Maybe with the same frequency, the comment has a whitespace between every single original characters. All in common is that the error cannot be within my code. There is no difference between the correct documents (ca. 95%) and the others.

Does anybody have an idea how I can workaround so that these issues don't appear anymore?
Or why this can happen?

I know I have an outdated SAP B1 at version 9.2 PL 10 Hotfix3. DI-API is linked to the install folder. Is this issue fixed in any later version?

(Current workaround is a cron job checking for wrong entries in the database and update those documents. Very uncool)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sounds like a DI-API bug. If you posted your code it would help confirm this.

Assuming it IS a DI-API bug, I would "dark side" it and just do a regular SQL update (bypass the DI-API), since it's just a UDF and there's probably not any business logic you need SAP to perform on these updates.

Alternatively, you could normalize your data and create a separate table linked via FK to your current table to house a single UDF per row (therefore not having to deal with the weird coma character issue).

As a third alternative, you could make of the SBO Post-Transaction Notification SP to monitor for your error case and perform the "fix" there, intead of in your cron-job.

Disclaimer: I have not worked with SAP in 4+ years.